# Как определить функцию - не член класса как встроенную?

Tags: c++

Как определить функцию - не член класса как встроенную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ее надо объявить с модификатором inline.

```
 inline void someFunc(int i, void * ptr)
 {
     // ...
 }
```